# AJAX timing issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have searched every where and I've been working on this for hours. Basically, I have an Ajax call fetching data from a webpage that fetches data from a database. This code is for a slideshow for a gallery of images. The entire function is shown below, however the part that is not working properly is the two lines of code that gets the height and the width of the images.

The images are being fetched properly, and they are displayed fine (well not really, but they show up). The lines that are querying the images' width and height, return 0 *most* of the time. There's about a 5% chance that they return the correct values. This causes the if statement directly afterwards to always evaluate to false, which makes wide images extend past the edge of the webpage.

This problem is only present in Webkit based browsers. Gecko based browsers do not have this issue.

I think the problem is that jQuery is trying to query the images before the Ajax call has finished its request. Is there any way to make jQuery wait for Ajax to be finished with its request?

```
function LoadForm() {
    GalleryDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: BaseAPI + "/PhotosByAlbum2",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "location": locationID, "ID": $.getQuery('ID') }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#slides").kendoListView({
        dataSource: GalleryDataSource,
        template: kendo.template($("#SlidesTemplate").html())
        });

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: BaseAPI + "/PhotosByAlbum2",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { "location": locationID, "ID": $.getQuery('ID') },
        success: function (d) {
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                $('#Show').append(
                    '<figure><img src="' + d[i].Path +
                    '" id="' + d[i].ID +
                    '"/><figcaption>Title: ' + d[i].Title + '<br />' +
                    'Description: ' + d[i].Description +
                    '</figcaption></figure>'
                );

/*these do*/    var imgheight = $("#" + d[i].ID).height();
/*not work*/    var imgwidth = $("#" + d[i].ID).width();

                if (imgheight < "768" && imgwidth > imgheight) {
                    $("#" + d[i].ID).addClass("wideimage");
                } else {
                    $("#" + d[i].ID).addClass("tallimage");
                }
            }

            $('#Show').innerfade({
                animationtype: 'fade',
                speed: 1050,
                timeout: 2000,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '500px'
            });
        }
    });

    $('#back').click(function () {
        window.location = 'Photos.aspx'
    });
}
```

Note: I've tried using `$.when(*ajax call here*).done(function() {*do stuff*});`. It behaved the exact same way.

And I've tried setting the `async` option to false. Same behavior.

I've also tried adding a `complete` event handler in the Ajax call. Again, it behaved the same way.

Comment: If you want to use image dimensions in a calculation, then you cannot run that code until the images have been successfully downloaded.  And, the only way to know when that has occurred is to use an `onload` handler for the images themselves.  If your code is working anywhere now, then that is ONLY because the images happen to be in the browser cache.  Your code would not work in any browser if the images were not in the browser cache.

Comment: The images are stored on a server and this code retrieves them via Ajax and, on success, displays them. It doesn't make sense why this code works 100% of the time in Gecko browsers and less than 5% of time in Webkit browsers.

Comment: It makes sense to me.  You AREN'T retrieving the images themselves via ajax.  You are retrieving the image filenames via AJAX.  You then create image tags, set the `.src` and the browser has to THEN load the images.  You try to then IMMEDIATELY reference the height and width.  If cached, some browsers will make the images available that quickly, some will not.  If not cached, no browser will have the images yet.  Your code is just written wrong.  You can't reliably access the height or width until the `<img>` tag fires its `onload` handler to indicate the image is now successfully downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, you have to wait for the images to load before you can reliably obtain their width and set the class you want on them.

Here's a way to restructure your ajax call to only process the images once they have been loaded and to only start the animation once the images have all been loaded and tagged appropriately:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: BaseAPI + "/PhotosByAlbum2",
    datatype: "json",
    data: { "location": locationID, "ID": $.getQuery('ID') },
    success: function (d) {
        var imagesRemaining = d.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = d[i].Path;
            img.id = d[i].ID;
            img.onload = function() {
                --imagesRemaining;
                var item = $(this);
                var imgheight = item.height();
                var imgwidth = item.width();

                if (imgheight < 768 && imgwidth > imgheight) {
                    item.addClass("wideimage");
                } else {
                    item.addClass("tallimage");
                }

                // now see if all images are loaded now
                // so all classes are set so we can now start the animation
                if (imagesRemaining === 0) {
                    $('#Show').innerfade({
                        animationtype: 'fade',
                        speed: 1050,
                        timeout: 2000,
                        type: 'sequence',
                        containerheight: '500px'
                    });
                }
            };
            $("<figure>").append(img).append('<figcaption>Title: ' + d[i].Title + '<br />' +
                'Description: ' + d[i].Description + '</figcaption>').appendTo("#Show");

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what you're talking about now. This isn't my code. I know it's terrible and trust me, it gets worse than what I posted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you can't access an image's height and width until it has been loaded. I would do something like this to listen for the load event:

```
$.each(d, function (idx, item) {
    $fig = $('<figure/>');
    $('<figcaption/>')
        .html('Title: ' + item.Title + '<br />Description: ' + item.Description)
        .appendTo($fig);

    $('<img/>')
        .load(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var height = $this.height();
            var width = $this.width();
            if (height < "768" && width > height) {
                $this.addClass('wideimage');
            } else {
                $this.addClass('tallimage');
            }
        }).attr('id', item.ID)
        .attr('src', item.Path)
        .appendTo($fig);

    $fig.appendTo('#Show');
});
```

Comment: Here's [a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/siceviwu/1/edit) that demonstrates the issue (at least before the image's cached).

Comment: It's not my question, just clarifying the answer to the issue you just brought up, with an example. :)

Comment: @estrar Oops! Didn't look closely enough. That is a helpful demo, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this ... of course, there could be a better way...

In the php script that runs at BaseAPI + "/PhotosByAlbum2" ... get each image's width and height, resize the images to the correct height and width for the slideshow, if needed, and then put those variables in the results array with Path, Title and Description ...

On the jQuery... read the array and adjust the width and height in your html...